# Is there semantic difference between this shan't and won't?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> "Which way did they go, Peeves?" Filch was saying. "Quick, tell me."
>
> "Say 'please."'
>
> "Don't mess with me, Peeves, now where did they go?"
>
> "[**A**] Shan't say nothing if you don't say please," said Peeves in his
>   annoying singsong voice.
>
> "All right - *please*."
>
> "NOTHING! Ha haaa! [**B**] Told you **I wouldn't say nothing if you didn't
>   say please!** Ha ha! Haaaaaa!" And they heard the sound of Peeves
>   whooshing away and Filch cursing in rage.
>
> –– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

It seems to be [B]’s highlighted part isn’t a remoteness expression but a backshifted preterite from “*I won’t say nothing if you don’t say please*.” Does Peeves use *won’t* in [B] to denote semantic difference from [A]’s *shan’t*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no semantic difference.  *shan't* is a contraction of *shall not*.  *shall* is just a modal auxiliary that indicates the future tense.  In **B**, the event is now over, so the future is changed to the past where *would* is now the proper modal auxiliary to indicate the past tense.

Peeves probably uses *shan't* instead of *won't* because he's from a bygone era where *shall* and *shan't* were much more prevalent than nowadays.

Comment: Isn't *shan't* still used in England?

Comment: @PeterShor- it might well be.